# Can I use bitbake to rebuild our system like CMake would have, when changes have been made in local repo's C++-files?

Tags: c++, yocto, bitbake

I have googled frenetically for answers but have not been able to find an answer yet.

I had like to build an image for our device containing our Linux system together with our end-user applications. The end-user applications reside in our git `repository: ourapplications-repo`. This works fine, i.e. invoking: `bitbake <ourapps>`, builds that image as desired. So far, so good.

However, it only works once. When I have edited our application files, which happens to be C++ files, I had of course like the `bitbake <ourapps>` command to re-compile and link affected C++ files, libraries and executables, just like running make would, and incorporating the affected files into a new fresh image that can be downloaded to our devices. Unfortunately, that does not happen.

Is there an easy fix for this, maybe adding something to `SRC_URI` or setting another **BB_VARIABLE** to ensure that files in `ourapplications-repo` are checked for any changes? Or is this totally wrong way to handle my need, maybe I really have to create an SDK and work with it using my vanilla build tools like `autotools` and CMake and when I am satisfied with my local changes I commit and push my changes to the git repo allowing `bitbake <ourapps>` to pickup those changes (if bitbake only pickup changes that have been pushed to the git repository)?

Or what is the best practice, how should I work with a common(?) setup like this?

```
This is how our simple and standard project structure looks like:
- project
-- build
-- poky
-- meta-freescale
-- meta-openembedded
-- meta-ourapplications
-- ourapplications-repo
```

```
--- build/conf/bblayers.conf:
BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""
BBLAYERS ?= " \
  ${TOPDIR}/../poky/meta \
  ${TOPDIR}/../poky/meta-poky \
  ${TOPDIR}/../poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  ${TOPDIR}/../meta-freescale \
  ${TOPDIR}/../meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  ${TOPDIR}/../meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  ${TOPDIR}/../meta-ourapplications \
  "
```

```
-- meta-ourapplications/recipes-ourapplications/images/ourapps.bb:
SUMMARY = "A small image capable of allowing our linux system to boot with our applications."
IMAGE_INSTALL = "packagegroup-core-boot ${CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL} ... foo"
inherit core-image
```

```
--- meta-ourapplications/recipes-ourapplications/foo/foo_1.0.bb:
DESCRIPTION = "Foo App"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"
PVBASE := "${PV}"
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}-${PVBASE}:${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
PV = "${PVBASE}+${SRCPV}"
SRC_URI = "git://${TOPDIR}/../ourapplications-repo;protocol=file;subpath=${BPN}"
S = "${WORKDIR}/${BPN}"
inherit autotools
```

```
--- ourapplications-repo/foo/
---- foo.cpp
---- Makefile.am
---- and so on...
```

Comment: With "When I've edited our application files," you mean change code and the you run bitbake or you mean change code commit the code to git and the you run bitbake? In the first case since the repo revision will be the same bitbake assumes via its hash that your recipe stayed the same and does not trigger a rebuilt so for this to work you have to commit your changes. If you commit your changes and a rebuild is not triggered it could be you found a bug in bitbake in this case to investigate it further you should look at the bitbake manual about build hashes etc.

Comment: @Falital yes, ultimately I'd like both cases to work, but I realize that the current model, where bitbake uses repo versioning, implies that it would only work if I commit my local code changes. But! I did commit my code changes still bitbake did not rebuild my apps!? So, maybe there is a bug lurking? Seems unlikely though for such a basic use-case? For that purpose I need to verify what goes on by producing appropriate log files. 1/2.

Comment: But that's another basic thing that I struggle with; how do I produce a log file that shows what actually happens during build time: How does bitbake invoke autotools and how does make compile the code? Can I instruct bitbake to invoke make with make's V=1 or VERBOSE=1 for cmake? Just using "bitbake -vDDDD recipe" does not show how or even which application files gets built! 2/2

Comment: Hi sorry for the late answer, bitbake generates logs for each task it executes in <tmp-dir>/work/<arch>/<recipe>/<version>/temp/log.<task>.24942 I tried out your issue and it seems to work as expected the moment code is changed in the repo the recipe is rebuild from scratch. You should probably add your bitbake output in your question, the Sstate summary shows how many tasks will be rerun in my case do_fetch fetches the new code, do_configure  runs cmake and do_compile runs make which all run after a commit.